# Google Forms Performance

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form that is running a script in the background that populates many drop down lists where the performance is very slow. It barely can load in all the browsers I am using because it is so slow. My question is that after all the info in the form is loaded, when I comment out the onOpen trigger's code it is still slow? Is a previous version of the script or last saved version running in the background or is there just too much info on this form?

In the code for my script there are many calls to google sheets in order to populate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple single read/write incidents (calls) will slow things down for sure.  To speed things up, try to group as many reads as possible into an array and then write them from the array.

You mentioned that a form is being filled out, you should be able to pull all of response information into an array through a single call.

Hope this helps.